# VBCodeProvider.CreateParser() returns Nothing?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction

Here is my code

```
Dim provider = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider()
Dim parser = provider.CreateParser()
```

`parser` is always Nothing. I know the Method `CreateParser` is obsoleted. How to create a VB code parser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parsers were never implemented.  In any of the language providers.  And never will, the method has been removed in .NET 4.0

There are alternatives, good looking ones in the top hits when you type "vb parser" in the google search box.